# Android SQLite rawQuery "WHERE" doesn't work

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to execute the following query:

```
try {

        if (db != null){
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT fp_id, COUNT(*) FROM rssi WHERE (mac = '20:aa:4b:d3:db:d6' and (rssi > -72 and rssi < -64)) OR (mac = '08:86:3b:f1:da:18' and (rssi > -63 and rssi < -55)) group by fp_id",null);
        }
        int cursorSize = cursor.getCount();
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);
    }
```

I get the cursorSize = 0 and this obviously means that the rawQuery() doesn't work. I tested it by removing WHERE clause and it worked fine. With WHERE it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated...

Comment: If an exception wasn't thrown then the syntax is valid. Thus, if there are 0 results the indication is clear: the data was *filtered out* according to the defined expression. So, *why*? It really isn't possible to provide a detailed explanation without seeing *actual data* (and types) and an *expected result*.

Comment: No exception was thrown. I tested the above query in SQLiteStudio on the targeted database and it worked fine and returned the expected results but here it never worked...

Comment: What is rssi? Is it both a table and a column in your table? It's confusing because you use it for both "FROM rssi" and "rssi > -72" etc

Comment: If the query returned the expected results *on the same database* (verify this: it's possible to easily use the wrong database!) then either 1. a different query is used, or; 2. the data changed between the queries. SQLite *does not* have any bugs/issues with executing such a query - thus it is probably one of the afore-mentioned issues.

Comment: @OleksiyDobrodum Yes I am using rssi as a table name and a field name in that table

Comment: You should rename either your table or the field with the same name. Not only it is ambiguous to humans, but the compiler might also be confused by it.

Comment: @AhmedNab : Are you using `SQLiteOpenHelper` and have you added either the `fp_id` column or `rssi` column since originally creating / running the app?

Comment: @Squonk I am using SQLiteOpenHelper but I am using fp_id and rssi columns from the beginning

Comment: Thank you guys for your help .... It's solved when I changed the name of rssi column and upgraded the database ...@OleksiyDobrodum please answer the question to accept it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is acceptable to use the same name for table and one of its columns in SQLite database, this won't work with android. Therefore, changing the name of the table or its field solves the problem. Note: It is important to upgrade the database (increase the version number)....